# Conditionally hide control based off visibility of another

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am working with a sub report that is passed a dataset of "Notes". I have the dataset added to a table with a filter that limits the Notes in the table based on certain conditions.

My table has its visibility set as `=CountRows() = 0` which will hide it if there are no results when it is filtered. My issues is that I want to show a textbox if the table is hidden that would say "There are no notes for this record."

Right now I have the visibility on the textbox set to `=Iif(CountRows("Notes") = 0, False, True)`. The issue with this is that it may not get hidden if the notes dataset has records but they are not displayed in the table because of the filter.

Is there a way to set the visibility based on the dataset with the same filter. Even simpler if it could be based on the visibility of the table. ie If the table is visible set visibility of the text box to be hidden

Comment: I don't know why you don't use the reverse condition for the TextBox. If something makes it impossible, you can show us the code that you use. I mean, not only the condition itself but the context in which the calls are made.

Comment: The table uses CountRows() to check it's visibility. I can't use that on the textbox because it has no rows. I need some way to reference the table and count its rows. I am not using any code just the designer. The above expressions are entered into the Visibility property of the textbox/table controls.

Comment: Can you show us the markup where the visibility property is set for both controls?

Comment: Right click table, click tablix properties, select visibility tab, select "Show or hide based on an expression", Set expression to "=CountRows() = 0"

Right click text box, select text box properties, select visibility, show or hide based on an expression, set expression to "=Iif(Parameters!RequiresFollowUp.Value Like "0", True, False)"